# Div same size every screen

Tags: html, css

On my website people can post images on a board and drag them around.

At the moment I use the following:

```
width:60%;

height 40%;
```

They can save their work.

The position is saved with margins so a image can be `top:50px;` and `left:150px;`

So its 50px to the right of the left border of the div and 50px down from the top of the div.

If they load their work it has to look exactly the same.

So if a image was on the lower right corner it has to be on the lower right corner when they load the file.

My problem is that if a user loads it on a different resolution it takes the margins and if the screen resolution is bigger on the next screen the image won't be on the lower right corner because there is more room cause 50% of 1200 is less than 50% of 1900.

So I have to use `width` and `height` in px but if i set 600px on the 1200 px it will look good but 600px on the 1900px won't look good.

Is there a way to use px but make it look good on every page?

**So basicly i want to use px but it must look the same (like when i use %) so the margins will be the same and the page looks the same no big open spaces on big resolutions.**

[image: Example]

on the example i made a board in 1366 and reopened it in 1024 the images take the margin from the left so it is out of the original board.

But the board (yellow background) is the same % of the screen.

So i want a board thats the same % of the screen but loads the images the same on every resolution so bottom right corner on 1025 screen must be bottom right corner of 1366 screen.

if i use px only the site looks diffrent on all resolutions and thats what i want t prevent.

Comment: Somde code or example would be useful.

Comment: A sample of your html would be useful or use http://jsfiddle.net/ to provide an example of the issue

Comment: Give fixed width to your body(or parent element).

Comment: i tryd to post the example code but it was edited away. the code is around 900 lines so its to big to write a jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

What it sounds like you have to do is adaptive theming or responsive design in CSS.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px; }
}
```

For a screen with a max-width of 1024px, set img elements.
You create some of these for each screen size you want to consider and voila, you should be able to have complete fine-grained control over what a user sees regardless of what their screen size is.

Comment: So what would happen if i go to a screen with 1900 px the whole set up of the page will look different and that is what i want to avoid.

Comment: I see - you're trying to leave the images the same size but make it still look good.
Maybe you could try the same approach that pinterest does, where they scale the pictures to the widths are the same and the aspect ratios are maintained, so the columns line up neatly. and the rows are allowed to be as large as they want. If nothing else, their CSS will reveal how they scale the pictures in a responsive way like I think you want.

Comment: If not that, I would suggest using JS to take the document.width (screen width for all intensive purposes) and using original_image.width, calculate out the absolute positions for each image. It is a little clunkier, but it might look better for you.